# How do you remember the order of the expressions in a for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop, mnemonics

It's a pretty simple question, I  always have to go [check here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and then I hit my head and say it's so obvious. But really after a week of not using it I usually  end up writing

```
for ($i = 1;  $i++; $i <= 10;) {
    echo $i;
}
```

some Mnemonic might help

Comment: By writing one million, billion `for` loops.

Comment: It might help you to think of the for loop as if it were a while loop.  Step 1 - initialize the counter, Step 2 - describe the while loop with the condition, Step 3 - iterate the counter within the loop.

Comment: @Brandon That's actually a really good way, you should post that as an answer. Rewrite the loop as a while loop to get `$i = 1; while($i <= 10) {echo $i; $i++;}`, and you've got the expressions in the right order

Comment: @mquander: That's how I learned it! Thankfully new programming languages build off of older ones, and nobody wants to redefine the indexed for loop paradigm. I'd be screwed if I started using a language that changed the order. (Foreach is a separate matter.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ICE`:

- Initialisation
- Check
- Execute

Comment: I'm always for icecream, aren't you? _I scream **for** **ice** -cream_

Answer (score 6):

Think logical! The order is the same as the expressions are evaluated.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    echo $i;
}
// is same as
$i = 0; // 1.
while ($i < 10) { //2.
    echo $i;
    ++$i; // 3.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They go in order.

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
```

expr1: Evaluated once at the beginning of the loop
expr2: Evaluated at the beginning of each iteration of the loop
expr3: Evaluated at the end of each iteration of the loop

You want to initialize first, check the condition second, and increment (or decrement) your counter last.

Comment: @Moak: Programming *is* my life.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
     START -> CHECK FOR DANGER -> MOVE AHEAD 

for( $i = 0 ;    $i < 100 ;         $i++    )
```

Hope it helps :-) 
Best of luck!

Comment: +1 I guess I am always in a rush and end up checking after I'm hanging over the cliff

Comment: In that case no one can save you! Gravity will not fail my friend! :)

Answer (score 2):

**F**
irst (initialisation)
**O**
Only while  (condition)
**R**
Rolling on (incrementing or decrementing)

Answer (score 0):

I may be daft but don't you want this structure:

```
for ( $i = 1;  $i <= 10; $i++ )
{
    echo $i;
}
```

I don't know of a Mnemonic to remember this structure I've always just seen it as:

`STARTING OFF; DO WHILE THIS; PERFORM AFTER EACH ROTATION`

Rather:

`DEFINE PRIOR TO EXECUTION; DEFINE EXECUTION LIMITS; DEFINE OPERATION FOR EACH ROTATION`

Comment: The _wrong_ structure was an example why he needed an mnemonic :)

Comment: of course i wanted that structure, my point was that I mix it up ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that the guard is always checked before the increment, so you write it before.

If you don't remember the guard is checked before the increment, you're in bigger trouble, because you don't know what the loop will do :p

Answer (score 0):

SAM

- Start your engine
- Are we there yet?
- Move